# how to lock service stack redis list in c#

Tags: c#, redis, locking, servicestack, servicestack.redis

In c#, using service stack redis, 
Based on the following url,

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisLocks

to lock a string entry, the following method is used.

```
RedisClient objRedisClient = new RedisClient... // redis working fine
objRedisClient.SetEntry("stringkey", "abcd");
using (objRedisClient.AcquireLock(strRedisKey))
{
  objRedisClient.SetEntry("stringkey", "efdh");
}
```

The above SetEntry code works fine for setting string values.
But when same code is used to lock a  list, it throws Redis Exception.

```
  using (objRedisClient.AcquireLock("listkey"))
  {
      objRedisClient.Lists["listkey"].Push("{}");
  }
```

Acquirelock method works fine, but pushing a new value to the list inside using statement throws the following exception.

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value,
>   sPort: 50371, LastCommand: RPUSH 97:Q {}

It is just a simple console application.
Without the acquire lock method, value gets successfully added to the list.

How to lock a redis list in c#?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using it wrong, the whole lock part is for a distributed lock and uses [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) command behind (the algorithm is explained also on the command page). This command is only for normal keys, not for other types (list, hashes etc). The lock is used for synchronization between different processes, so there is no point in using something else than a normal key. 
If you want to make sure, open a `redis-cli monitor` and see exactly what is the command your client is sending to Redis (it should be a `SETNX`).

Answer (score 1):

The key in the lock, is not the key of the data structure you're trying to protect but any normal [STRING](http://redis.io/commands#string) key that's used to identify the lock, e.g. you could use the keyname as a namespace for a normal STRING key with:

```
using (objRedisClient.AcquireLock("listkey.lock"))
{
    objRedisClient.Lists["listkey"].Push("{}");
}
```